# Windows CMD cannot use Python Virtualenv or Django commands

Tags: windows-8, command-line, python, django, virtualenv

I'm trying to use python Virtualenv and Django. I have successfully installed both using Pip. On every tutorial I've found, it tells me to open CMD and type in a command. For example:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>django-admin startproject mysite
```

- docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>virtualenv pymote_env
```

- pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>mkvirtualenv myproject
```

- docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/windows/

Every one of these commands return

```
'...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I cannot find any solution to this. Is it worth running a virtual Linux Ubuntu machine? I'm running Windows 8 and using Python 3.4.3 32-bit.
Any help well be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to add Python VirtualEnv to your system's path so CMD can find the executables and execute them

Comment: @fernando.reyes do you know which directory I should add? Thanks!

Comment: You can check it in the installation manual: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#configuring-python

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to setup a virtual environment
using:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

then you create a virtual name

```
mkvirtualenv test
```

then you get your own environment

some times it doesn't work, you need to delete the environment then again you install it

uninstall using:

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper-win
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

install using:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

you'll get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run with `python -m` prefix. For e.g. `python -m virtualenv pymote_env`

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but I had a similar issue and for me it was a matter of access privileges. When using regular windows cmd or shell it did not work.

In Visual Studio Code I chose "select default Shell" and chose Bash.

After this I could run all the commands which previously didn't work. Specifically, getting terminal/bash to run as a venv.

I hope this might solve it for you.